# Can I Register a Class for NSNotifications? Can I use Class Methods with NSNotifications?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications, selector

I'm working on a class for my iPhone app, and I'd like it to register for and be aware of application state changes (`UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`, etc).  Is there a way to register a class for notifications without having to keep an instantiated object in memory?  I just want to have the appropriate notifications call the class to init, do some stuff, and then leave memory again.

Right now I have the following in the init method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(handleEnteredBackground) 
                                             name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object: nil];
```

and this method elsewhere in the .m file of the class:

```
- (void) handleEnteredBackground {
    NSLog(@"Entered Background"); }
```

I instantiate the class once under `applicationDidLoad`, but since I don't do anything with it I presume ARC kills the object from memory and the app crashes (without any useful error codes, mind you) when I go to close it.  If I switch `handleEnteredBackground` to a class method with a "+" sign, I get invalid selector errors when I close the app.

The end goal is to instantiate a class once in the lifecycle of an app and have it be able to respond to app state changes without any additional code outside the class. Assume iOS 5 + Xcode 4.2+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into [singletons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

You can easily create an object that lasts through the whole application lifecycle.

```
+ (id)sharedObserver
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static YourObserverClass *sharedObserver = nil;

    dispatch_once(&once, ^{ 
        sharedObserver = [[self alloc] init]; 
    });

    return sharedObserver;
}
- (void)startObserving
{
    // Add as observer here
}
```

Now you can call `[[YourObserverClass sharedObserver] startObserving]` and you don't have to worry about retaining it etc.

Comment: This sounds like a great solution...  I'll give it a shot and accept the answer once I've had a chance to try it out!

Comment: No problem. Just write here if you have more questions.

Comment: If you build the singleton just because of this selector issue only, downvote!

Answer (score 20):

The following should work:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: [self class]
                                         selector: @selector(handleEnteredBackground:) 
                                             name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object: nil];
```

The selector itself:

```
+ (void) handleEnteredBackground: (NSNotification *) notification
{
}
```

You don't have to unregister the observer, because the class object cannot be deallocated or otherwise destroyed. If you need to unregister the observer for other reasons, you can:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: [self class]];
```

Comment: Costique: Xcode won't let me use [self class] to register as an observer from within the class - it tells me "Received type '<classname>' for instance message does not declare a methods with selector '<classname>'

Comment: @Amos Yes, if you register with the `NSNotificationCenter` in a class method, use `self` instead of `[self class]`. The reason is that `self` refers to an instance of a class inside instance methods, and to the class object inside class methods.

Comment: @Amos: what? which call are you getting this warning from?

Comment: @Costique: yes, but `[self class]` also refers to the class inside the class object. so there shouldn't be any errors

Comment: Hey guys - per the accepted answer, I ended up implementing a singleton structure for my class and registered the one instance to receive notifications. It worked quite well!